# JavaScript and jQuery toggle on main DIV not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm making it where their is some buttons, and when one is clicked it makes the hidden DIV with contents unhide, this is what I have:

**`HTML`**

```
<div id="disArea">   <!--The toggled Dac diplays in this area.-->
            <div class="Dac  1">
                <p>Dac 1/p>
            </div>

            <div class="Dac  2">
                <p>Dac 2/p>
            </div>

            <div class="Dac  3">
                <p>Dac 3/p>
            </div>

            <div class="Dac  4">
                <p>Dac 4/p>
            </div>

            <div class="Dac  5">
                <p>Dac 5/p>
            </div>
    </div>

            <div class="ibox" onclick="disToggle('.1')">Button 1 (Displays the Dac 1)</div>
            <div class="ibox" onclick="disToggle('.2')">Button 2 (Displays the Dac 2)</div>
            <div class="ibox" onclick="disToggle('.3')">Button 3 (Displays the Dac 3)</div>
            <div class="ibox" onclick="disToggle('.4')">Button 4 (Displays the Dac 4)</div>
            <div class="ibox" onclick="disToggle('.5')">Button 5 (Displays the Dac 5)</div>
```

Please remember that the div's with the class of "Dac" are hidden until jQuery executes the following (well, that is what I want to do, but it doesn't):

**`jQuery / JavaScript`**

```
function disToggle(DacNumClass)
{
  $("ibox").click(function()
  {
    $(DacNumClass).toggle();
  });
}
```

I've done this by using a JavaScript function with a argument, the argument calls out the Id, or class that I need to `.toggle()`.  This could be the complete wrong idea, correct me if I am wrong.  How this works is ever Dac has a number class along with it, and the function argument is the class e.g. `divToggle()`

And I have lastly my CSS, not sure if this important at all, but here it is:

**`CSS`**

```
#disArea {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background: green;
}

        .Dac {
        display: none;
        }

.ibox {
background: red;
display: block;
width: 125px;
height: 125px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

It doesn't seem to be toggling? what have I done wrong?

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pTUZL/7/)

**`EDIT`**

*Fixed link with the `/p>` instead of `</p>`

Also, is it possible to have only one Dac Div open at a time?

Comment: Just so you know.
toggle() - Removed in version 1.9. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp

Comment: @Jason not this implementation of [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), it is the [.toggle(function, function)](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) that got removed

Comment: Yep your so right Arun this example and use is fine, its just the two functions toggle that got removed :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `disToggle` itself is a click handler you should just toggle the target element inside the method.

Also since the method `disToggle` is used as a inlined handler it should be added to the global scope, by default jsfiddle will add the given script in `window.onload=function(){...}` wrapper which will make the `disToggle` method a private one to the onload handler. You need to select `No Wrap - Body/Head` in `Left Side Panel -> Second Dropdown`

```
function disToggle(DacNumClass) {
    $('.Dac').not(DacNumClass).hide()
    $(DacNumClass).toggle();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hBAQg/)

A more jQuery-ish solution

```
<div class="ibox" data-target=".1">Button 1 (Displays the Dac 1)</div>
<div class="ibox" data-target=".2">Button 2 (Displays the Dac 2)</div>
<div class="ibox" data-target=".3">Button 3 (Displays the Dac 3)</div>
<div class="ibox" data-target=".4">Button 4 (Displays the Dac 4)</div>
<div class="ibox" data-target=".5">Button 5 (Displays the Dac 5)</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $dacs = $('.Dac');
    $('.ibox').click(function () {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $dacs.not(target).hide();
        $(target).toggle();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kguT2/)

Comment: Thanks! but is it possible to only have one Dac div open at once?

Comment: Wow, super.  Thanks, thanks, and thanks again. This is exactly what I needed! (I'll vote best once I can)